# Does using a return value change the behavior of a function c?

Tags: c, return-value

I had this piece of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("%x", i);
}
```

to which, when i give character 'a' as input, it spits out some random numbers in the output like "73152c" or "66152c" etc.
But when I change the code to this,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i;
    int j = scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("%x %d", i, j);
}
```

output will always be "2 0" for same input.
So, does using the return value of a function changes its behavior?
I'm using windows 10 64-bit with gcc 8.1.0 and compiling with no switches.

Comment: Provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem and the actual input.

Comment: Likely you are not inputting valid numbers, and getting undefined behavior as `i` is not initialized and not set by `scanf` in either case. Undefined behavior often manifests as behavior that changes when seemingly irrelevant things in the source code are changed.

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of inputs read - so if you get `j` set to 0 - it means scanf did not read anything (possibly due to invalid number input). That, combined with the fact that `i` is indeterminate, means you're invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow those 3 lines are my entire main function. Input is any english character. I tried a, b, c, d.....

Comment: @PaulHankin yup, it is essentially undefined behaviour. But still those random values of i (which i think were the previous garbage value and is untouched by scanf due to erroneous input), changes to exactly 2 on every run of the code when I use j.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB, if you accept that you are exercising UB, then what is the question? "Undefined" means what it says.

Comment: UB must be at least reasonable. Can it be random sometimes and ordered sometimes? That too with exact same inputs?!!!

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB: Yes, there are things that can explain some undefined behavior, based on how compilers work or how computers work and so on. But people cannot give you explanations without information. Whatever the behavior is, it is **not** defined by a snippet of code you provide. Provide a **complete program** that reproduces the behavior, and state the compiler you are using, including the version and the switches. Then maybe an explanation for what you observe can be figured out.

Comment: @PaulHankin: There is no undefined behavior here. The value of `i` is indeterminate, which means using it must result in either a trap representation (C 2018 3.19.2), which common modern C implementations do not have for `int`, or a valid value (3.19.3), albeit one that can change on each use. The rule making use of an indeterminate value of an object with automatic storage duration undefined behavior does not apply because the address of `i` is taken (6.3.2 2).

Comment: @EricPostpischil, my entire main function consists of these three lines. I wrote this snippet to verify the behavior of scanf on wrong input. I'm using gcc 8.1.0 on my windows 64 bit machine.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB: I am sorry, but we are not interested in allegations such as “my entire main function consists of these three lines.” We want to see a **complete program**, including `#include` statements and the declaration of `main` and anything else that may be there. Having the complete program source code, and the compiler versions and switches (which you did not state) allows us to generate the same assembly code that your compiler generates, which can then be examined to see what is going on. And we also want to see the **exact input** you provide.

Comment: @EricPostpischil i have edited the question now. I'm not sure about what you mean by switches, I think you are talking about cmd inputs for gcc during compilation like -O2, -funsafe etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using godbolt.org to examine the assembly code generated by GCC 8.1.0 with no switches, here is the assembly code for the `main` routine in your first program:

```
push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp
sub     rsp, 16
lea     rax, [rbp-4]
mov     rsi,rax
mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
mov     eax, 0
call    __isoc99_scanf
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
mov     esi, eax
mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
mov     eax, 0
call    printf
mov     eax, 0
leave
ret
```

and here is the code for your second program:

```
push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp
sub     rsp, 16
lea     rax, [rbp-8]
mov     rsi,rax
mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
mov     eax, 0
call    __isoc99_scanf
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
mov     esi, eax
mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
mov     eax, 0
call    printf
mov     eax, 0
leave
ret
```

They differ in two places. In the first, this instruction passes the address of `i` to `scanf`:

```
lea     rax, [rbp-4]
```

In the second, it is this instruction:

```
lea     rax, [rbp-8]
```

These are different because, in your second program, the compiler has included space for `j` on the stack. For whatever reason, it decided to put `j` at `rbp-4`, the space used for `i` in the first program. This bumped `i` to `rbp-8`.

Then the code differ where the first program passes `i` to `printf`:

```
lea     rax, [rbp-8]
```

and the second passes `i` and `j`:

```
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
```

And now we see why your programs print different things for `i`. In the first program, because a value is never put into `i` (because `scanf` makes no assignment for `%d` when the input contains the letter “a”), your program prints whatever data happened to be in `[rbp-4]` when `main` started. In the second program, your program prints whatever happened to be in `[rbp-8]`.

What is in these stack locations is whatever is left from the start-up code that runs for `main` is called. This is special start-up code that sets up the C environment. It may do things with addresses in your program, and some addresses in your program are deliberately randomized in each execution by the program loader to foil attackers. (For further information, look into [address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).) It appears when the start-up code is done, it leaves some address in `[rbp-4]` and zero in `[rbp-8]`. So your first program prints some address for `i` and your second program prints zero.

So, the differences in this case were not caused by using or not using the return value of `scanf`. They were caused by having more or fewer variables, resulting in changes in where things were put on the stack.

This can of course change if you upgrade your C implementation and a different version of the start-up code is used or the compiler generates different code. Turning on optimization in the compiler, as with the `-O3` switch, is likely to change the behavior too.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` returns the number of items successfully converted and assigned, or `EOF` on an end-of-file or error condition.

The `%d` conversion specifier tells `scanf` to skip over any leading whitespace, then read decimal digits up to the first non-digit character; that non-digit character is left in the input stream, and any digits that have been read are converted to an integer value and assigned to `i`.

If the first non-whitespace character is not a digit, then `scanf` stops reading immediately, returns `0` to indicate nothing was converted and assigned, *and `i` is unchanged*.

In the first snippet you don't initialize `i` before reading it and it is not being updated, which is why the output is seemingly random.  You've technically invoked *undefined behavior* at this point by using that indeterminate value.  One possible outcome of undefined behavior is getting a different result each time.

In the second snippet `j` gets the return value of `scanf`, which is `0`.  As for why `i` is always set to `2`, again, since you're trying to use that indeterminate value, the behavior is undefined.  Another possible outcome of undefined behavior is that you get the *same* result each time, for no apparent reason.

Comment: Re “You've technically invoked undefined behavior at this point by using that indeterminate value”: No, technically, they have not. Using an indeterminate value results in either a trap representation or an *unspecified value*, which is a “**valid** value of the relevant type“ (C 2018 3.19.3 1, bold added), and, if the implementation does not have a trap representation for the type, the result must be some valid value, albeit possibly different on each use. The rule about using an indeterminate value of automatic storage duration being undefined does not apply since `i`’s address is taken.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the behaviour of scanf is not changing.. You can conform this by including this line, `printf("%x", i);` before scanf. Instead here, my compiler initializes i to 2 when I use j. Otherwise i will not be initialized, and will have some random garbage value.
I don't think entering input of wrong type is undefined behavior - Correct me if I'm wrong. Instead it keeps the corresponding and following pointers untouched, and immediately returns from scanf. I ran multiple runs and every time value of i was unchanged.
Now the surprising thing is that, when j is declared, why i is always initialized to 2!!

Comment: This is not an **answer**, just additional information that belongs into the **question**.

Comment: @thebusybee now tried to make it more like an answer for that question...

Comment: It still contains a question (_why i is always initialized to 2_), and adds nothing to John's answer, which is quite complete, BTW.